# How to reload just a part of an html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I've been trying for days and I'm in desperate need of help because it's the last thing I need to do for my thesis.

I have a an **index.html** page with a stepper and a graph inside:

```
<html>
<style>
  #stepperTwoLabs {
    display: none;
}

  #stepperThreeLabs {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<head>

    <title>Training</title>
    <meta name="description">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/architecturetree/css/tree.css" />
    
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph"> <!-- View the graph-->
    <h1><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Training</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>  
     
  <div id="stepperTwoLabs">
    <div class="stepp2">
    </br></br></br>
      <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">
        <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
          <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed"> 
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe0" name="myIframe0" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled = false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe1" name="myIframe1" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="End" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <h1>
              All done!
              </h1>
              <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
              </h5>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">START</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
        </md-steppers>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="stepperThreeLabs">
    <div class="stepp3">
    </br></br></br>
      <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; step4.disabled = true; selected = 0">
        <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
          <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe2" name="myIframe2" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe3" name="myIframe3" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab3" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe4" name="myIframe4" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 3; step3.completed=true; step4.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="End" md-complete="step4.completed" ng-disabled="step4.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <h1>
              All done!
              </h1>
              <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
              </h5>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2">PREV</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
        </md-steppers>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The stepper is initially hidden but when I click on a node of the graph inside it, it becomes visible and is loaded with several labs to be carried out.

The code portion inside the **.js** is as follows:
(the click function is launched with the `.on event (click, click)` using d3.js)

```
var click = function (d){
  document.getElementById('stepperTwoLabs').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('stepperThreeLabs').style.display='none';
  if(d.parent.name == 'Buffer Overflow' || d.parent.name == 'Password Cracking' || d.parent.name == 'Denial of Service' ||
     d.parent.name == 'Privilege Escalation' || d.parent.name == 'Web Hacking' ) {
       vm.numlab=d.children.length;
       if (d.children.length==2) {
        document.getElementById('stepperTwoLabs').style.display='block';
        for(var i=0; i< d.children.length; i++) {
          var lab=d.children[i].name;
          $('#iframe'+i).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
      }
      } else if (d.children.length==3) {
        document.getElementById('stepperThreeLabs').style.display='block';
       for(var i=0; i<d.children.length; i++) {
        var lab=d.children[i].name;
        var j=i+2;
        $('#iframe'+j).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
          }
      }
    }
}

// Double click to scroll down in the page up to the stepper
var dblclick = function (d) {
  if (d.children.length==2) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".stepp2").offset().top}, 'slow');
  }
  else if (d.children.length==3) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".stepp3").offset().top}, 'slow');
  }
}
```

If  it is the first sequence of steps and therefore the first click, everything is fine because the stepper is loaded for the first time. **The problem arises when** I click a new node of the graph to load another set of labs to be carried out because the stepper starts from the end, **or rather from the step at which I had stopped previously**. . What I would like is to make sure, perhaps by updating the content of the stepper in the index.html, that we can start from the first step every time a node of the graph is clicked.

EDIT: When I start another laboratory it starts from the end because these are loaded in the stepper (always the same of the index.html) and the state in which it is left is that of the last step. I could start from the beginning by inserting a button like this: `<md-button class = "md-raised md-primary" ng-click = "step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0"> START < / md-button>` but the problem is that this has to be done by clicking on the node and I can't do anything about it (at least I think). basically I know why this happens and to solve it you will only have to refresh a part of html.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is your thesis, you should be able to explain why it starts from the end. This is your code, so: at which line does the code make that decision, and (now that you've been forced to look at that line), what is it about that line that starts at the end instead of the start? And then of course as immediate follow-up, now that you know where and why it happens, what have you already tried to make it start at the beginning? (for which it's not unimportant to explicitly state what "the beginning" means. Because if you can do that, you can capture it in a variable, and then later use that)

Comment: When I start another laboratory it starts from the end because these are loaded in the stepper (always the same)  and the state in which it is left is that of the last step. I could start from the beginning by inserting a button like this: <md-button class = "md-raised md-primary" ng-click = "step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0"> START < / md-button> but the problem is that this has to be done by clicking on the node and I can't do anything about it (at least I think). basically I know why this happens and to solve it you will only have to refresh a part of html.

Comment: but remember: details on your code go in your post. Even if someone asks for them in a comment, update your post so that _everyone_ reading your post from then on gets a more complete picture, with proper markup and formatting (which, as you can see, comments are not useful for).