# Refresh element inside html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I've been trying for days and I'm in desperate need of help because it's the last thing I need to do for my thesis.

I have a an **index.html** page with a stepper and a graph inside:

```
<html>
<style>
  #stepperTwoLabs {
    display: none;
}

  #stepperThreeLabs {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<head>

    <title>Training</title>
    <meta name="description">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/architecturetree/css/tree.css" />
    
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph"> <!-- View the graph-->
    <h1><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Training</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>  
     
  <div id="stepperTwoLabs">
    <div class="stepp2">
    </br></br></br>
      <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">
        <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
          <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed"> 
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe0" name="myIframe0" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled = false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe1" name="myIframe1" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="End" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <h1>
              All done!
              </h1>
              <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
              </h5>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">START</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
        </md-steppers>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="stepperThreeLabs">
    <div class="stepp3">
    </br></br></br>
      <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; step4.disabled = true; selected = 0">
        <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
          <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe2" name="myIframe2" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe3" name="myIframe3" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="Lab3" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <iframe id="iframe4" name="myIframe4" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 3; step3.completed=true; step4.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
          <md-step label="End" md-complete="step4.completed" ng-disabled="step4.disabled">
            <md-content>
              <h1>
              All done!
              </h1>
              <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
              </h5>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2">PREV</md-button>
            </md-content>
          </md-step>
        </md-steppers>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The stepper is initially hidden but when I click on a node of the graph inside it, it becomes visible and is loaded with several labs to be carried out.

The code portion inside the **.js** is as follows:
(the click function is launched with the `.on event (click, click)` using d3.js)

```
var click = function (d){
  document.getElementById('stepperTwoLabs').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('stepperThreeLabs').style.display='none';
  if(d.parent.name == 'Buffer Overflow' || d.parent.name == 'Password Cracking' || d.parent.name == 'Denial of Service' ||
     d.parent.name == 'Privilege Escalation' || d.parent.name == 'Web Hacking' ) {
       vm.numlab=d.children.length;
       if (d.children.length==2) {
        document.getElementById('stepperTwoLabs').style.display='block';
        for(var i=0; i< d.children.length; i++) {
          var lab=d.children[i].name;
          $('#iframe'+i).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
      }
      } else if (d.children.length==3) {
        document.getElementById('stepperThreeLabs').style.display='block';
       for(var i=0; i<d.children.length; i++) {
        var lab=d.children[i].name;
        var j=i+2;
        $('#iframe'+j).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
          }
      }
    }
}

// Double click to scroll down in the page up to the stepper
var dblclick = function (d) {
  if (d.children.length==2) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".stepp2").offset().top}, 'slow');
  }
  else if (d.children.length==3) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".stepp3").offset().top}, 'slow');
  }
}
```

If  it is the first sequence of steps and therefore the first click, everything is fine because the stepper is loaded for the first time. **The problem arises when** I click a new node of the graph to load another set of labs to be carried out because the stepper starts from the end, **or rather from the step at which I had stopped previously**. . What I would like is to make sure, perhaps by updating the content of the stepper in the index.html, that we can start from the first step every time a node of the graph is clicked.

When I start another laboratory it starts from the end because these are loaded in the stepper (always the same of the index.html) and the state in which it is left is that of the last step. I could start from the beginning by inserting a button like this: `<md-button class = "md-raised md-primary" ng-click = "step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0"> START < / md-button>` but the problem is that this has to be done by clicking on the node and I can't do anything about it (at least I think). basically I know why this happens and to solve it you will only have to refresh a part of html.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this angular? Because you're using lots of jQuery here, and my guess is if you used a proper angular approach this problem can be solved trivially. Lines like `document.getElementById('stepperTwoLabs').style.display='none';` are making me think you're using angular as a wrapper, not as actual frontend technology. Your problem basically sounds like "how do I change the contents of a div based on app state", which is kind of all angular does in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisG Can you give me more information about the solution you found? that line of code you are referring to is a solution that I found to solve another problem that arose and that is to show the stepper when clicking on the graph node.

Comment: That line is how to hide an element if you *aren't* using a framework like Angular. With angular though you'd use [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf). If you had to google how to make an element visible with JS, chances are you haven't properly learned how to use Angular (or JS) yet. I recommend doing the official tutorials here: https://angular.io/docs (but best get a solid grip on JS basics first)

Comment: my previous solution was as follows:  `<div ng-include="ctrl.numlab==2 && 'views/stepper-two-labs.html' || 'views/stepper-three-labs.html'"></div>` but it didn't work that way either .. So you say I should find a way to do it with the ng-if? Thanks, I'll try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload just a part of an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975906/how-to-reload-just-a-part-of-an-html-page)